# how to store "file://" in string format in c#

Tags: c#, string

i want to store file:// as constant string to check is a particular String is URL.

```
public readonly String[] URLHEAD = { "http://", "https://","file://","\\\\" };
```

but but am not able to do it.

Comment: what problem do you have?

Comment: file:// is appearing in blue with an underline unline "http://" or "https://" which appear in orange.

Comment: Can you show us some code that explains the problem ?

Comment: just color? and what? it's IDE settings only. not an error at all

Comment: class Constants
    {
        
        public enum ATTRIBUTE_MATCH_FLAG { NONE, MATCH, NOMATCH, NOKM };
        public enum ELEMENT_MATCH_FLAG { NONE, MATCH, NOKM };
     
        public const String URL = "URL";
        public const String ALPHANUMERIC = "ALPHANUMERIC";
        public const String NONE = "NONE";
        public const String NEEDTOBEMATCHED= "NEEDTOBEMATCHED";
        public static readonly String[] URLHEAD = { "http://", "https://","file://","\\\\" };

    }
} the "file://" is blue with a line below. IS this an error or it will work.

Comment: Of course it does work! Why don't you try it yourself? simply do a loop of URLHEAD and print it!

Comment: Please do not put code in a comment!  Edit your question instead and add the code to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just the coloring indicating that it's a clickable link, exactly as if you start typing `www` after `http://`.

[image]

I wonder what made you think that you were *unable to do* something. You could compile and run your code anyway!

I highly suggest you try to pay more attention, as this "*issue*" was NOT really worth a question here.

Comment: In retrospective, I didn't mean to sound so harsh. It was just a strong advice. :) My concern was at which point you thought _"I cannot continue, I'm blocked, it doesn't work, I need to ask someone else"_.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work even if the color is blue. It is just an IDE setting as @Backs mentioned. But if you are really concerned with how it is marked up in your IDE then you can turn off the setting.

I'm assuming you are using Visual Studio.

Go to `Tools\Options\Text Editor\C#\General\Enable single click URL navigation`